# Loading a pickeld file using pickle.load() fails after some successful attempts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I saved a np.array using

```
    pickle.dump(np.array(freq_timeseries), open(
"fname.p","wb"))
```

This works fine and after that I can access this file by using `pickle.load()`. After some time (meaning after some successful `pickle.load()` uses) the attempt to load this file using `pickle.load()` fails with an unpickling error.

Previously it failed with `'invalid load key 3'`. But as of late there is no specific error message anymore but simply the `'Unpickling error'`. I created the file anew and after that it works for some time but fails again after some `pickle.loads()`.

I use the same machine with the same version of python. I am very confused and think I misunderstand how to use pickle.

Best regards,

Phil

Comment: Wild guess: you're opening the file but never closing it, which somehow causes problems. Try doing `my_file = open("fname.p","wb"); pickle.dump(np.array(freq_timeseries), my_file); my_file.close()` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is as Kevin commented, that you're not closing the files, consider re-writing using the `with` statement and it'll auto-close.

Comment: yeah that totally makes sense. Pretty "new" to programming and I just added this and the file is being created right now. Just takes 30mins or something like that ;)

Comment: gives me invalid load key '5' now...ah well

Comment: Did you do something like this?

    with open('fname.p', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(np.array(freq_timeseries), f)

Comment: yes. I did exactly that but some kinda error still persists. I believe it has something to do with the file since it works in all other cases. But I believe your answer helped me so I think it was the right one.